# Getting unauthorized access error when implementing SAML 2.0 based applications

Tags: reactjs, saml-2.0

I am getting this error when clicking on Login with Microsoft button

```
We're unable to complete your request
unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. 
If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
```

I am working on Front-End and I am also passing the correct client-id but still getting this error
[image]

Here is the code --

```
const App = () => {   
  const loginHandler = (err, data, msal) => {
    console.log(err, data);
    // some actions
    if (!err && data) {
      // onMsalInstanceChange(msal);
      console.log(msal);
    }
  };

return (
    <div className="app">
      <MicrosoftLogin clientId={config.clientId} authCallback={loginHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using OAuth2 / OpenID Connect to login with an application that uses SAML?

You need to create an [enterprise application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-saml).

Comment: I have created an enterprise application only

Comment: Yes, but you need a SAML stack to connect to it. You are using an OAuth stack. ClientID is not a SAML parameter.